# Calculated Column based on [Start Time] showing series start date instead of event start date on recurring event

Tags: 2013, list-view, calendar, calculated-column, recurring-events

On my Calendar list I have recurring events. I have a view that wants to filter on the [Start Time] of the event but that field isn't available in the filter options of a view. After some research I found that the work around is to create a calculated column with a formula of =[Start Time] and this should create a column that shows the start time of the recurrence and this field should be available in the view filter.

The column IS available in the view filter, however it is returning the series start date&time instead of the recurrence event.

So as an example I have a Recurring Event ("Event1") that recurring every Friday @ 10:30am starting 12/10/2010 and going forever.

I create a Standard view with Expanded Recurring Events and can see all the iterations of the this event, however where the "Start Time" for a particular recurrence shows 1/6/2017 10:30am the calculated column shows 12/10/2010 10:30am.

I have seen this referenced many places as the work around, so what am I doing incorrectly. Why is my calculated column showing the series start instead of the event start?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85263)

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this in a few places, and found this formula.  It works!  Use this calculation for your [Start Date] and it should work.  It will not adjust fixed date/times, just the one's which have a starting date listed as "All Day".

=TEXT(IF([End Time]=[Start Time],[Start Time],IF(MOD(ROUNDUP(([End Time]-[Start Time])*24,0),24)=0,[Start Time]+1,[Start Time])),"dd mmm yyyy")